# Why the merge CSS files not populating?

Tags: magento-1.9, css, cache, server-setup

I have recently migrated a Magento website which had been using **merge_css_files** successfully.

On the new server, however, I cannot get it to work and would very much appreciate any advice on the matter. The system will create the CSS files in `media/css` but they are always blank (unpopulated). I suspect that this might be something to do with the server itself as it worked previously on the old server.

I have already toggled Merge CSS on and off, flushed the caches multiple times, deleted the files from the `media/css` folder, updated all file and folder permissions, checked the ownership in FTP.

Perhaps you have experienced the same or could advise on a possible solution?

Comment: I may be way off here, but is there space on the disk?

Comment: Did you maybe miss the trailing slash at the end of the (new?) base url on the new server? I had once a similar issue...

Comment: This *really* seems like a permissions thing. Create but not append.

Comment: @benmarks - I agree. Also is the media folder a symlink? or a mount to another physical drive?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. In response: Marius, plenty of space left. Anna Volkl, base urls trailing slash is already in place. benmarks, all premissions are set correctly. I even ran a test & set absolutely everything to 777, still the issue continued. @ProxiBlue, I'm not sure what a symlink/mounted to another physical drive is. Simply put the cms is installed on a shared/cloud hosting server. Everthing is where you would expect a default installation to be. I even tried installing a brand new and fresh Magento install on the cloud server and it still couldn't create the css files properly.

Comment: Assuming you have ssh access to the server, you can easily tell which mount the media directory exists on (and how much space is there too) by running `df -h <path_to_directory>` and compare that to the results of the same command run with the path to the public directory. That said…are your resized product images being written to the media/catalog/products/cache directory? You might check SELinux for errors if it'e enabled on the server.

Comment: Hi Daniel, 
This may be a bit of a new question but when you page load is it showing the css? if it is fantastic we know the css is linking properly.
If it isnt however, have a look in your source at the css file generated. Could you please provide a website URL so maybe we could all help?

Comment: Thanks for your replies David & Adam. Everything else is writing correctly. Images are doing what they're supposed to do etc and there are no server space issues. @Adam when I turn on Merge CSS. It renderes no CSS at all, when you click on the page and view source, in the head it is showing the css file being called however when you look at that css file in /media/css the css files are completely blank or empty. For some very odd reason which I am still in the dark about, the server or magento system won't populate the merged css files. I migrated this site and it worked fine before.

Comment: @Adam, I cannot provide a link to the site demonstrating it not working because it is now live and I cannot leave it sitting there broken. The Merge CSS files for the site www.powercut.co.uk is currently turned off. Although I did just check again and the merge css files is still not working.

Comment: Daniel: So when you turn the merge on it breaks yes? How are you turning merges on, and when you turn it on can you copy the new css code?
I would recommend copy everything move it over to a new location as a testing zone, that way you can keep this website publically accessable without conversion risk.

Comment: @Adam, thanks for your reply. It is possible to turn css merge on in one of two ways: 1) Admin backend System/Configuration/Developer/Advanced/CSS Settings or via database (e.g. myphpadmin) by finding the merge_css_files under the core_config_data table and changing the value from 0 to 1. It creates a new css file in Media/CSS but the files are completely empty.

Comment: Daniel: have you tried the admin backend instead of the database? there could be more than one table entry that is changed, unfortunately I dont know if that is the case, just trying to eliminate all problems :)

Comment: @Adam, yes as stated before I have tried both the database and the admin backend.

Comment: Okay have you cleared the caches in var/ folder? and are you aware if tmp isnt writable it will write into the server not the magento files? that could be one cause, as its a result of when you move a magento to a different domain.

Comment: Hi @Adam, as you can see from the original question posted that all the caches have been cleared. This includes the var/cache and media/css folders. That was the very first thing I tried. I suspect this is a server issue / server configuration issue as it worked perfectly on the previous server under the same domain.

Comment: In distributed systems where media folder is generally shared by symlink the problem occurs with file_put_contents(). see my answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

> *Simply put the cms is installed on a shared/cloud hosting server*

FWIW, that statement says two different things. You *did* do a great debugging thing by checking with a vanilla install.

The only thing you can do is debug `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::_mergeFiles()` and/or `Mage_Core_Helper_Data::mergeFiles()`. I believe the latter of these is where execution is breaking out.

Also, ensure that `display_errors` and developer mode are enabled (I would just do this in *`index.php`* temporarily given the environment issues). Also ensure to check error logs in *`var/log/`*. You may want to verify that session & cache files are able to write to the *`var`* directory as well.

***Edit:***

**Before you debug, confirm that the site looks as you would expect with merging disabled.**

Since you are using FTP you want to keep debug iterations to a minimum. So, you should use Magento's native logging:

```
Mage::log(__LINE__,null,'merge.log',true);
```

You'll want to sprinkle this throughout the methods in question. I'd start with the `mergeFiles()` method from the core helper:

```
public function mergeFiles(array $srcFiles, $targetFile = false, $mustMerge = false,
    $beforeMergeCallback = null, $extensionsFilter = array())
{
Mage::log(__METHOD__,null,'merge.log',true); //for some context
    try {
        // check whether merger is required
        $shouldMerge = $mustMerge || !$targetFile;
        if (!$shouldMerge) {
Mage::log(__LINE__,null,'merge.log',true);
            if (!file_exists($targetFile)) {
                $shouldMerge = true;
            } else {
                $targetMtime = filemtime($targetFile);
                foreach ($srcFiles as $file) {
                    if (!file_exists($file) || @filemtime($file) > $targetMtime) {
                        $shouldMerge = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // merge contents into the file
        if ($shouldMerge) {
Mage::log(__LINE__,null,'merge.log',true);
            if ($targetFile && !is_writeable(dirname($targetFile))) {
                // no translation intentionally
                throw new Exception(sprintf('Path %s is not writeable.', dirname($targetFile)));
            }

            // filter by extensions
            if ($extensionsFilter) {
                if (!is_array($extensionsFilter)) {
                    $extensionsFilter = array($extensionsFilter);
                }
                if (!empty($srcFiles)){
                    foreach ($srcFiles as $key => $file) {
                        $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                        if (!in_array($fileExt, $extensionsFilter)) {
                            unset($srcFiles[$key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (empty($srcFiles)) {
                // no translation intentionally
                throw new Exception('No files to compile.');
            }

            $data = '';
            foreach ($srcFiles as $file) {
                if (!file_exists($file)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $contents = file_get_contents($file) . "\n";
                if ($beforeMergeCallback && is_callable($beforeMergeCallback)) {
                    $contents = call_user_func($beforeMergeCallback, $file, $contents);
                }
                $data .= $contents;
            }
            if (!$data) {
                // no translation intentionally
                throw new Exception(sprintf("No content found in files:\n%s", implode("\n", $srcFiles)));
            }
            if ($targetFile) {
                file_put_contents($targetFile, $data, LOCK_EX);
            } else {
                return $data; // no need to write to file, just return data
            }
        }

        return true; // no need in merger or merged into file successfully
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you do not see *`var/log/merge.log`* being created, first drop that call in at the very end of *`index.php`*; if you still don't see it then there is something amiss with your environment and you will need your host to help. If you do see it but it contains no content from the helper, then you need to step back to the `_mergeFiles()` call in the design package model. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply @benmarks. I can ensure you that the var folder is writable. I don't understand how to debug the model and helper you mentioned above. After the vanilla install I knew it was a server issue but I have no idea what to do with it or how to work around it. I will look into debugging and displaying errors ... but again, I don't know how to take that forward either. Thanks again for your input and help!

Comment: Updated with some debugging steps.

Comment: I'm afraid I might need a little more guidance. I found and updated the code above in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php. I refreshed the caches, toggled the Merge CSS files on (still broken) and then off again. Emptied the caches again and did not see any file called merge.log in 'var/log'. Am I going about this right?

Comment: Add that logging call to the absolute end of *`index.php`* and see if the file gets written. If it doesn't then you have an environment issue.

Comment: Thanks @benmarks. I added Mage::log(__LINE__,null,'merge.log',true); to index.php and it created merge.log in var/log. This is what the contents of that file say: 2013-09-19T15:55:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): 88

Comment: After putting the code in index.php I put it in the helper and model data files. The result was another line for each in merge.log which was the same is the result above (exept the timestamp sligtly different). Does this tell you anything? Thanks

Comment: It tells me that you need to debug in `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::_mergeFiles()`, which for some reason isn't calling the helper's `mergeFiles()` method. In other words, your problems are upstream i.e. earlier in the stack.

Comment: I added Mage::log(__LINE__,null,'merge.log',true); pretty much anywhere it mentioned "mergeFiles" in app/code/core/Mage/core/Model/Design/Package.php. When you say "i.e. earlier in the stack." Did you mean further up in the Package.php file, or something completely different? Here is what my var/log/merge.log file looks like now: 2013-09-19T15:55:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): 88
2013-09-19T15:58:28+00:00 DEBUG (7): 88
2013-09-19T15:59:03+00:00 DEBUG (7): 88

Comment: I've just noticed that on every page there a section in the footer has appeared titled "Profiler." I cannot have this showing on every page. I've deleted all the code from the helper, model and index.php files and yet it is still there. Have you any idea how to remove this? For your information however it states the following: Memory usage: real: 31457280, emalloc: 30927248

Code Profiler Time Cnt Emalloc RealMem

Comment: `System > Config > Developer > Enable Profile = "No"`, or set the IP restriction in that area to use your IP address.

Answer (score 2):

I have just done some research hope this helps:

**RESOURCE 1**

> Magento Merged CSS Clear Not Working + Solution
>
> If you are having an issue with Magento and the optional Merge CSS
>   Files (beta) turned on and it not updating with recent CSS changes,
>   you may appreciate this.
>
> Unlike other cached elements that are stored in var/cache, Magento
>   stores the cached and minified CSS files in media/css
>
> If you simply delete the contents of this folder, your CSS changes
>   should kick in as Magento is forced to rebuild these files.
>
> There is an option in cache management to flush CSS storage but for
>   some reason this wasn’t working for me. Could be a permissions issue
>   or something else I am not sure, we simply needed to get this change
>   implemented (emergency live site fix) so flushing this folder manually
>   did the trick.
>
> Hope it helps someone else looking for Magento merged CSS clear not
>   working, Magento CSS cache, Magento CSS Files beta

[[Source of content]](http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/magento/magento-merged-css-clear-not-working-solution/)

**RESOURCE 2**

> To make changes in core configurations and have them stick (local.xml, base urls, etc.) you need to clear your Magento code
>   cache, often by actually manually deleting the mage--? subfolders in
>   var/cache.
>
> Cached configuration can cause all sorts of headaches including having
>   the base urls still pointing back to the original Magento installation
>   (different folders, different server) despite the fact that you can
>   use phpMyAdmin and see that the rows have been updated in the
>   database. Configuration will not be reread from the database until the
>   cached configuration information is deleted.
>
> Another place where stuff gets stuck is in your APC op-code cache if
>   you’re using it. Use the apc.php administration page to clear that as
>   well. Stopping and restarting Apache will achieve the same result
>
> And last of all, IF YOU DO NOT HAVE PERMISSIONS SET PROPERLY ON
>   var/cache AND var/tmp SO THEY’RE BOTH READABLE AND WRITABLE TO YOUR
>   WEB SERVER, Magento may store the cached information in the system
>   /tmp directory which means that no amount of clearing Magento’s cache
>   will make the cached configs go away until someone reboots the server,
>   the system /tmp directory gets cleared and Magento seemingly
>   automagically reads its configs. Or you're told about it and you have
>   access to delete the Magento cache out of /tmp. Here's some
>   documentation of this happening in the system temporary storage folder
>   off of root (see images)
>
> Note: If you save a backup copy of your local.xml file, make sure to
>   rename it to something like local.xml.sv1 or you will find that
>   Magento still reads it.

[[Source of content]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515237/magento-cache-not-get-clear)

I hope either of these methods help, if you have transfered domains, im guessing its number 2 more than anything however if you are shared that may be a problem as you wont have full server access, I hope either can help.

And as you have said you have cleared **VAR/** and **MEDIA/** You will be right with the server config and i would look at resource 2.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, I'm sure that in the majority of cases that either of the above would work. It's also worth noting that you should try to manually clear everything in the **Media/CSS** folder too but none of these scenarios works for me as I think it might be a server issue.

Comment: do you have access to the server? because it could be cached in /tmp as noted in resource two, and if you have a shared hosting you will NOT have access to this folder, in which you need to request to your hosts to check that folder and clear anything magento related within that folder.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, it is shared. I'll ask the host to clear the tmp folder and see what happens.

Comment: Clearing the server /tmp folder did not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Did your template break after merging? If not, then I'd refresh the FTP window. For example, Transit from Panic caches the results when you change folders, so when you change back after adding/deleting files, the folder still shows the old contents. But if the template breaks after merging, this won't be the issue.
Also check "Current Configuration Scope:" that you're in the right store and that all stores are checked to "Use Website".

Answer (score 1):

For me, Claudflare was a problem.

Go to cPanel or Claudflare dashboard and just purge cache. Then the change will be magically applied. I spent hours to figure this out.

It seems like not many people using Magento had the same problem as me. I found this solution on Drupal forum.

I hope this might help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

It is realted to the fact that your media folder is referenced by a **symlink** and/or any **distributed file system**. (generally media/ folder is shared between multipe servers)

The problem resides in the function below because of the **LOCK_EX**: 
in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php : Line :753

```
if (!$data) {
    // no translation intentionally
    throw new Exception(sprintf("No content found in files:\n%s", implode("\n", $srcFiles)));
   }
   if ($targetFile) {
      file_put_contents($targetFile, $data, LOCK_EX); // THE PROBLEM IS JUST HERE
   } else {
       return $data; // no need to write to file, just return data
   }
```

The problem is with the use of **file_put_contents**($targetFile, $data, **LOCK_EX**)

changing it with use of flock should solve the problem :

```
    $fp = fopen($targetFile, "w+");
    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
        //Mage::log("INFO : Acquire Exclusive lock on " . $targetFile, null, 'merge_js_css_debug.log');
        ftruncate($fp, 0); // Erase Content
        fwrite($fp, $data); // Write data
        fflush($fp); // Free content befor unlock
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // Unleach lock
        //Mage::log("INFO : Write complete on " . $targetFile);
    } else {
        Mage::log("ERROR : Impossible to lock File " . $targetFile . "<br>");
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

So As final solution you can rewrite the subject core file (app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php) like below :

```
    if (!$data) {
    // no translation intentionally
    throw new Exception(sprintf("No content found in files:\n%s", implode("\n", $srcFiles)));
   }
   if ($targetFile) {
    $fp = fopen($targetFile, "w+");
    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
        //Mage::log("INFO : Acquire Exclusive lock on " . $targetFile, null, 'merge_js_css_debug.log');
        ftruncate($fp, 0); // Erase Content
        fwrite($fp, $data); // Write data
        fflush($fp); // Free content befor unlock
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // Unleach lock
        //Mage::log("INFO : Write complete on " . $targetFile);
    } else {
        Mage::log("ERROR : Impossible to lock File " . $targetFile . "<br>");
    }
    fclose($fp);
   } else {
       return $data; // no need to write to file, just return data
   }
```